# "Could not determine which "make" command to run. Check the "make" step in the build configuration." Qt creator

Tags: c++, c, qt, mingw

I installed several times the qt creator but it never cost me as much as in my current PC; First I used the installer that always had on my Pendrive (that of Qt 5.8), told me that I could not download some repositories, I downloaded version 5.9 of the same installer, with the same result. After trying to install it several times and it did not load I went to another house where I managed to install it, although I had to be very aware of many errors coming out of missing libraries (while installing Qt 5.9). After this I had to download the sp1 for my win7 OS through "windows updates" to run the Qt creator, but later, when loading, creating or running a project, I would say in console (it does not matter if it is GUI) the following : "Could not determine which" make "command to run. Check the" make "step in the build configuration." I would very much appreciate your help to anyone who wants to advise me, because I have already had many problems with my computer, from losing everything (the previous hard drive had installed original win10) to a series of very annoying setbacks like this. I cannot post images, I have no more than 10 reputations.

edit 1: there are the images:

```
https://ibb.co/jcNp05
https://ibb.co/hMyU05
```

The problem is that the video you posted is for linux, but i thank you for your help. I need now more he

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set a valid compiler to build your project. As any compiler is not set, it is asking you to check the configuration.

For example in my PC, I get the following as compiler output:

11:13:33: Running steps for project ListViewExample...

11:13:33: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.

11:13:33: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe"

C:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug

Here you can observe that **C:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make** is the make compiler which builds the application.

You can set the compiler path here:
**Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits**. Select the kit displayed and select a
valid compiler.

[image: Screenshot of my configuration]

### How to add mingw compiler at the time of installation

[image]

### Reference Video for similar issue

**You can try this youtube video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unkGHMgffmI).** Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: how can I writte those commands in windows?(sudo apt install cmake g++)

Comment: You don't need to do this. **mingw** is the c++ compiler for windows. In fact the screenshot attached is from my windows PC. When you install Qt, it displays the options to install this compiler. I have edited my answer you can cross check it.

Comment: Plus 1. Thanx for detailed ans.