# “Could not determine which ”make“ command to run. Check the ”make“ step in the build configuration.” Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I installed Qt Creator 5.10.1 and when I built the project I had a error : "Could not determine which ”make“ command to run. Check the ”make“ step in the build configuration.”.

I have already install Qt on another PC and I saw this question ["Could not determine which "make" command to run. Check the "make" step in the build configuration." Qt creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838817/could-not-determine-which-make-command-to-run-check-the-make-step-in-the-b/44839469#44839469?newreg=a74b62b6a48249eaa25c739aac54a499)

but in Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits I have lot of Desktop Qt 5.10.1 so he have 1.

Sorry for my english as I'm french and I 13 so my skill is limited

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lg17a54pdgj9923/screen.png?dl=0

Comment: In your screen shot you have one valid kit _Desktop Qt 5.10.1 MinGW 32 bit (default)_  if you use this default kit for your project, do you get the errors?

Answer (score 4):

You can see the selected build kit in the Build Kit Selector located at the bottom left of your window (button with the hammer image).

You can also manage any of the Build Kits if you go to `Tools > Options > Build & Run`.

For any build kit in Qt, you need to have the following components:

**Device** - You can build your application or your desktop/local computer or a remote computer or device with a different or same kind of processor.

**Compiler** - Specify the location of a compatible C++ compiler here. Clicking on manage takes you to the `Compilers` tab where you can add as many compilers as you want. If you are on Windows, you will most likely have a `MinGW` compiler installed along with Qt at this location - `C:\Qt\Tools\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`. You can also select a compiler installed with Visual Studio which will be a `MSVC` compiler.

**Qt Version** - The last thing you need to specify is the `Qmake` builder which is in `Qt Version`. You will need to select this with the appropriate C++ compiler that you previously selected in this build kit. If you have a MinGW C++ compiler, then specify a path for a MinGw `qmake.exe` and if it is a `MSVC` compiler then select a `MSVC` based `qmake.exe`. On Windows, all your `qmake.exe`'s will be located at `C:\Qt\<Qt-version>\<compiler-version&type>\bin\qmake.exe`.

Keep in mind that if you are building the project for a different processor or operating system, you will need an appropriate compiler and Qmake selected.
Once you select these properly (and select that build kit in selector), your project will build properly.

Comment: Well explained Aditya

Comment: From your screenshot, I would recommend selecting the Desktop Qt 5.10.1 MinGW 32 bit build, if it not already selected. If it fails to build with this, you can edit it as explained above.

Comment: Thank you @MohammadKanan :)

Comment: Thank for your answer but i have another problem

Comment: What do you think the problem is? Can you share what compiler andqmake you've linked the build kit to?